# Ajax is returning empty string

Tags: php, ajax

Below is my AJAX call to my test.php page. When returned, I'm getting a blank line.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: 'action='+action+'&workOrderID='+value+'&wid='+wid+'&eid='+eid+'&lastName='+lastName+'&firstName='+firstName+'&finalComment='+comment,
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        alert("Work Order NOT Updated.");       
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        alert("Work Order Updated.");
    }
});
```

If needed, this is the page that it is being sent to. Currently, I am testing to make sure the AJAX is sending something.

```
if ($_POST['action'] === "update") {
    return json_encode($_POST['workOrderID']);
}
```

The variables in the AJAX are set, but I can not seem to find out what the issue is.

Comment: Well, not just AJAX but PHP in general.  At the top-level code you would use `echo` to emit data to the response.  *Functions* would use `return` to return values to calling code, which is entirely different from emitting to the response.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this bro :

```
if($_POST['action'] === "update"){
    echo json_encode($_POST['workOrderID']);
}
```